# Creating .as files with Adobe AIR

Tags: flash, air

Is it possible to write text using Adobe AIR so that I can save it as an actionscript class file?

I want to generate my own classes using air, I just have not found anything that explains how I can save say a text file as a .as file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. ActionScript files are text files with an .as extensions, so if you can create text files, you can create ActionScript files (by filling them with valid ActionScript code and give them an .as extension).

Comment: e.g.    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
   try
   {
    fileStream.writeUTFBytes(content);
   }
   finally
   {
    fileStream.close();
   }